# Here-API AutoComplete Search returns only one postalCode result

Tags: here-api

I try using the here api to get a list of postalCodes based on City name, e.g.:

https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=&app_code=&country=DEU&query=Berlin

I get this city result:

```
{
  "label": "Deutschland, Berlin, Berlin, Berlin",
  "language": "de",
  "countryCode": "DEU",
  "locationId": "NT_DKX2wfaWICS7JyfHmCOJhB",
  "address": {
    "country": "Deutschland",
    "state": "Berlin",
    "county": "Berlin",
    "city": "Berlin",
    "postalCode": "10117"
  },
  "matchLevel": "city"
},
```

with postalCode: 10117. This is correct, but Berlin has a lot more postalCodes. Is it possible to get all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Geocoder API provides the matching location information for the query you provide. In your case, since Berlin matched to a city it provides city level information where postal code provided would refer to center of the city. If you are interested in getting all postal codes in a location then Platform Data Extension (PDE in Fleet Telematics API) is the right service. ROAD_ADMIN_FC1..5 layers provides postal code information. Please look into developer website or tcs.ext.here.com/ for PDE information.

```
https://pde.api.here.com/1/tile.json?&layer=ROAD_ADMIN_FC1&level=9&tilex=496&tiley=358&region=WEU&release=18142&url_root=pde.api.here.com&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx
```

Answer (score -1):

you'll find an example of what you want to achieve there: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/pde_postal_bounds